# Autocomplete with 2 elements : marklogic

Tags: marklogic

By using word lexicon or range index I can have autocomplete values for one element, what if I want to search on 2 elements(firstName & lastName) and display the result of these 2 elements

Any idea how to achieve the same in marklogic

e.g

```
Employee1.xml
<employee>  
  <firstName>Sundeep</firstName>  
  <lastName>Kumar</lastName>  
  <age>Money to Nothing</age>  
</employee>

Employee2.xml
<employee>  
  <firstName>Sunny</firstName>  
  <lastName>Kumar</lastName>  
  <age>Money to Nothing</age>  
</employee>

Employee3.xml
<employee>  
  <firstName>Sundar</firstName>  
  <lastName>Kumar</lastName>  
  <age>Money to Nothing</age>  
</employee>

Input 1 : Su
Expected Output : Sundeep Kumar
                  Sundar Kumar
                  Sunny Kumar

Input 2 : Kumar
Expected Output : Sundeep Kumar
                  Sundar Kumar
                  Sunny Kumar
```

Answer (score 2):

The ideal way do do this is to denormalize first and last name elements into a a new element when you import those documents into your database, so you would have something like `<firstAndLastName>Sundar Kumar</firstAndLastName>`. Then you could use your current wildcard solution to query those values.

If that's not an option, then you can do the equivalent of a join in MarkLogic, known as a "shotgun OR" or "scatter query". Here, you can use wildcards to query the values from each of the first and last name elements. Then you can "shotgun" them into a second query that retrieves pairs of values from documents where either element matches one of those values. This is all still done in indexes, so it should meet any autocomplete performance requirements.

```
let $autocomplete := 'Su'
let $qnames := (xs:QName('firstName'), xs:QName('lastName'))
let $values := cts:element-value-match($qnames, $autocomplete||'*')
let $element-refs :=
  for $q in $qnames
  return cts:element-reference($q)
let $tuples := 
  cts:value-tuples($element-refs, (),
    cts:element-range-query($qnames, '=', $values))
for $t in $tuples
return string-join(json:array-values($t), ' ')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Can you please help with java equivalent code for performing join (Scatter or 'shotgun or') ?

Comment: @SundeepKumarMehta You can save this as an XQuery module and call it from Java. Otherwise, you should probably ask another question and specifically note the Java interface you're using.

Comment: Can I use value co-occurences to fetch the above details from 2 elements since its also retrieved from index?

Comment: @SundeepKumarMehta Yes, however `cts:value-tuples` and `cts:value-co-occurences` both use indexes. The main difference is that co-occurences is limited to 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

This is what one can use to get Autocomplete on Both names

```
let $inputText := "su"
let $Names := <Names>
{
  for $each in doc()/employee[(fn:contains(lower-case(firstName/text()), lower-case($inputText))) or (fn:contains(lower-case(lastName/text()), lower-case($inputText)))]
  let $firstName := $each/firstName/text()
  let $lastName := $each/lastName/text()
  return <Full-Name>{concat(lower-case($firstName)," ",lower-case($lastName))}</Full-Name>
}
</Names>
```

Comment: The question is about how to perform autocomplete, and this answer does not address that.

Comment: @wst, i just found out what i did was wrong. See above the updated query

Comment: For any significant number of names it's unlikely that this query will perform fast enough to meet the latency requirements of autocomplete (usually about 150ms).

Answer (score 0):

Is the high-level Search API an option for your application? If yes, I'd recommend adding a new element to your data containing regularized names, create an element range index, then use `search:suggest` (http://docs.marklogic.com/search:suggest?q=search:suggest&v=8.0&api=true) for your typeahead UI component. This is one way to achieve the 100-ms response time acceptable for autocompletion.